# How to set currentTime in video.js in Safari for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, video.js

Other is ok, but the setting of `currentTime`:

I tried some ways like:

```
videojs("example_video_1", {}, function() {
    this.currentTime(200);
    this.play();
});
```

And this is not working.

```
videojs("example_video_1").ready(function(){
    this.currentTime(200);
});
```

This also doesn't work.

```
var dom = document.getElementById('example_video_1');
dom.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
    dom.currentTime = 100;
}, false);    // ok for no video.js
videojs(dom);
```

Not working. Even reverse the line of `addEventListener` and init videojs.

And I tried the videojs event.

```
var player = videojs("example_video_1");
alert(player.addEvent);
alert(player.addEventListener);
```

these API all not exists, so how do I bind Event in `videojs`?

Answer (score 11):

This is how I got the video playback on a defined position at startup (it removes the problem that the video first started and only afterwards jumped to a video position):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var timecode = 120;
    var initdone = false;

    // wait for video metadata to load, then set time 
    video.on("loadedmetadata", function(){
        video.currentTime(timecode);
    });

    // iPhone/iPad need to play first, then set the time
    // events: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#mediaevents
    video.on("canplaythrough", function(){
        if(!initdone)
        {
            video.currentTime(timecode);
            initdone = true;
        }
    });

}); // END ready
```

Comment: This is the right answer and this works on Mac Safari too.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, by lucky, i found an example in https://github.com/videojs/video.js

```
var dom = document.getElementById('example_video_1');
videojs(dom, {}, function(){
    this.on('loadedmetadata', function(){
        this.currentTime(500);
    });
});
```

this is work, the API to bind event is player.on('event', fn);

videojs is cool~

Comment: For me, this worked for Safari on MacOS, but not on iOS.

Comment: For me, it works only sometimes. I see the position is set and then it jumps back. Any ideas how to fix it?